# How do I compare dates in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model class with a class variable `due_date`:

```
due_date = models.DateField()
```

I want to output in the Django admin if the object is due or not based on today's date.

My function is as follows:

```
def is_due_today(self):
    dd = self.due_date
    today = datetime.date.now
    return dd - today > 0
```

But my output is:

```
(None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtracting two `datetime` objects in Python gives you a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object, which you can't compare to an integer.  You can, however, get something like `total_seconds()` from it to see if it's nonzero.

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
# wait 3 seconds
>>> now2 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> td = now2 - now
>>> td.total_seconds()
3.266
```

So in your case, the code would look something like (untested):

```
def is_due_today(self):
    dd = self.due_date
    delta = dd - datetime.date.today()
    return delta.total_seconds() > 0
```

Comment: note: total_seconds() available from python 2.7 and beyond. Before that, use something like:            
* if delta < timedelta(hours=1):

Answer (score 2):

`today` should be:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
```

Subtracting two datetime date objects gives you a timedelta.

```
>>> a - datetime.date.today()
datetime.timedelta(0)
>>> a = datetime.date.today()
>>> a - a
datetime.timedelta(0)
>>> a - a == 0
False
>>> 
>>> a - a == datetime.timedelta(0)
True
```

Also, if you are checking if something is due today, your conditional statement might need to be changed:

```
today - today isn't going to be > 0
```

If you are checking for past due:

```
return self.due_date < datetime.date.today()
```

Checking for due today:

```
return self.due_date == datetime.date.today()
```